# How to update Array field?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Im using Firebase Firestore and want to update an array field under a userprofile with the latest chat thread's id.. Im guessing that I have to pull the entire array (if it exists) from the chat node under that user, then I need to append the new id (if it doesnt exist) and update the array.. It works when theres only 1 value in the array then it fails after that with the following error:

> Transaction failed:  { Error: Cannot convert an array value in an array value.
>         at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:554:15 code: 3, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }

and here is my firebase cloud function, can anyone tell me where im going wrong ?

```
  exports.updateMessages = functions.firestore.document('messages/{messageId}/conversation/{msgkey}').onCreate(  (event) => {
    /// console.log('function started');
    const messagePayload = event.data.data();
    const userA = messagePayload.userA;
    const userB = messagePayload.userB;     
    // console.log("userA " + userA);
    // console.log("userB " + userB);  
    // console.log("messagePayload " + JSON.stringify(messagePayload, null, 2) );    

  const sfDocRef = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userB}`);

  return admin.firestore().runTransaction( (transaction) => {

      return transaction.get(sfDocRef).then( (sfDoc) => {

          const array = [];
          array.push(...[event.params.messageId, sfDoc.get('chats') ]);

          transaction.update(sfDocRef, { chats: array } ); 

      });
  }).then( () => {
      console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
  }).catch( (error) => {
      console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
  });  

  });
```

Comment: This is one of reasons Firebasers recommend not storing data in arrays. Your current data looks like it'd be better off as a set, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays. That way adding a chat ID is as simple as `sfDocRef.update({ "chats."+event.params.messageId, true })`.

Answer (score 4):

You're nesting arrays in your code here:

```
const array = [];
array.push(...[event.params.messageId, sfDoc.get('chats') ]);
```

This leads to an `array` with two values, the first one being the new `messageId` and the second value contains an array all of your previous values, e.g.

```
[ "new message id", ["previous id", "older id"] ]
```

This type of nested array is something that Firestore (apparently) doesn't allow to be stored.

The solution is simple:

```
const array = [event.params.messageId, ...sfDoc.get('chats')];
```

---

The fact that you have to first load the array to then add a single element to it is one of reasons Firebasers recommend not storing data in arrays. Your current data looks like it'd be better off as a set, as shown in [the Firestore documenation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays):

```
{
  "new message id": true, 
  "previous id": true, 
  "older id": true
}
```

That way adding a chat ID is as simple as:

```
sfDocRef.update({ "chats."+event.params.messageId, true })
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, While I have you here. Is this the right way to lay out a chat app in Firestore. My thinking is to store chat ids under the user node, then on the main message inbox get these ids and use them to reference the messages node with all the individual messages. It seems counter-intuitive to me but I cant think of a more optimal way to do this using Firestore

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked further into the matter, and I would follow the advice that Frank gave you in his post; allocate the data in collections rather than with arrays as they have greater versatility for Firebase [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model). Researching under the examples listed in the Firebase website looking for anything related to a chat, I’ve found the data structure and code for messages that are used by Firechat as they might be of use for you.

In the source code, they use a collection for the their message-id -userId pair with the following topology [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GIwf.png) :
[image: Topology of the Example]

The exact way how the saving is executed at the repository is [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUWgw.png) :
[image: Append sentence]

It executes an append of the message into the Room-id collection. Instead of this structure, you could use an userID - messageID pair as it might fit you better.